# Trying to solve number of ways of making coins, but I can't figure out where my logic is flawed

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dynamic-programming

am trying to solve this problem.

You are working at the cash counter at a fun-fair, and you have different types of coins available to you in infinite quantities. The value of each coin is already given. Can you determine the number of ways of making change for a particular number of units using the given types of coins?

```
Sample Input 1
10 4
2 5 3 6

Sample Output 1
5
Explanation 1

There are five ways to make change for n = 10 units using coins with values given by C= [2,5,3,6]:

1) {2,2,2,2,2}
2) {2,2,3,3}
3) {2,2,6}
4) {2,3,5}
5) {5,5}
```

The code I've written:

```js
const getWays = (n, c) => {
  let m = c.length

  let matrix = Array.from(new Array(m + 1), () => Array(n + 1).fill(0))
  console.log(matrix);


  for (let i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
    matrix[i][0] = 1
  }
  for (let j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    matrix[0][j] = 0
  }

  for (let i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
      if (c[i] > j) matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j]
      else {
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j] + matrix[i][j - c[i]]
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(getWays(10, [2, 5, 3, 6])) //5
```

I can't figure out where my logic is breaking in the assignment of values to the matrix.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No return value in the `getWays` function

Answer (score 0):

Check this recursive algorithm.

```js
function getWays(n, c) {
  const len = c.length
  if (n < 0 || len < 1) return 0
  if (len == 1) {
    if (n % c[0] == 0) return 1
    return 0
  }
  let cnt = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = c[i]; j <= n; j += c[i]) {
      cnt += getWays(n - j, c.slice(i + 1))
    }
  }
  if (n % c[len - 1] == 0) cnt++
  return cnt
}

console.log(getWays(10, [2, 5, 3, 6])) //5
```